# How to get access to Observable.range() index from onNext()

Tags: java, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I have written below RXjava code to upload list of images in to a server. From the server side it will send a response referring to uploaded image link. I keep these images in my local storage, if only particular image successfully uploaded i should remove delete that image from local storage.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final String accessToken = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.access_token), "");
    final ArrayList<String> imageLinks = new ArrayList<>();

    Observable
            .range(0, ImageFilePaths.size())
            .flatMap(new Function<Integer, ObservableSource<ProductImageUploadResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<ProductImageUploadResponse> apply(Integer index) {

                    JSONObject imageUploadKJsonObj = new JSONObject();

                    try {
                        imageUploadKJsonObj.put("version", "1.0");
                        imageUploadKJsonObj.put("action", "uploadimage");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    File file = new File(ImageFilePaths.get(index));
                    MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Image", file.getName(),
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
                    RequestBody accessTokenRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), accessToken);
                    RequestBody imageUploadRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), imageUploadKJsonObj.toString());

                    return APIservice.uploadProductImageRx(accessTokenRequestBody, imageUploadRequestBody, filePart);
                }
            })
            .retry(3)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<ProductImageUploadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(ProductImageUploadResponse productImageUploadResponse) {

                    if(productImageUploadResponse.getResult() == 0){
                        imageLinks.add(productImageUploadResponse.getImage());
                        //Delete image from local storage
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // Handel this
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // Next operation
                    submitRequestEnquiryProduct(imageLinks);
                }
            });
```

The problem is how to get access to the index of uploaded image in `onNext()` method to delete it. If index is accessible from `ImageFilePaths` array list i can get the path and delete it. Is there a way to get this done ?

Comment: Map the `APIservice.uploadProductImageRx`'s returned `Observable` onto a `Pair` of `Integer` + `ProductImageUploadResponse`.

Comment: ```int[] index = { 0 };```. ```index[0]++;``` in ```onNext```.

Comment: @akarnokd flat map can't return Pair it should be observable.

Comment: @zhh what happen when error occurred ?

Comment: If error occurs then ```index``` is the one which causes the error.

Comment: so how to get index to on error ? I don't think solution is simple as that ?

Comment: Who said the return of the callback of the flatMap should be a Pair? Map the result of the `uploadProductImageRx`: `APIservice.uploadProductImageRx(accessTokenRequestBody, imageUploadRequestBody, filePart).map(res -> Pair.of(index, res))` and adjust the return type to `Observable<Pair<Integer, ProductImageUploadResponse>>` and `Pair<Integer, ProductImageUploadResponse>` where needed.